# Sqliteexception while updating timestamp?

Tags: android, sqlite, timestamp

I have this code:

```
      String sql="UPDATE  LAST_OPEN  SET  LAST_OPEN="+DATE+"  WHERE  STUDENT_ID ="+STUDENT_ID+"    AND   ITEM_ID="+ITEM_ID+" AND   ITEM_NAME="+ITEM_TYPE+";";

db.execSQL(sql);
```

Where LAST_OPEN field is timestamp.I tried to run the same query in SQlite Browser it was working fine.But when this Sql is executed in app it shows this:

```
       02-13 13:12:39.468: E/AndroidRuntime(2366): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
       02-13 13:12:39.468: E/AndroidRuntime(2366): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "13": syntax error: UPDATE  LAST_OPEN  SET  LAST_OPEN=2012-02-13 13:12:39  WHERE  STUDENT_ID =5    AND   ITEM_ID=1 AND   ITEM_NAME=Activity;
       02-13 13:12:39.468: E/AndroidRuntime(2366):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
       -13 13:12:39.468: E/AndroidRuntime(2366):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1727)
        02-13 13:12:39.468: E/AndroidRuntime(2366):     at com.cuelearn.databases.last_open.update(last_open.java:205)
      02-13 13:12:39.468: E/AndroidRuntime(2366):   at com.cuelearn.main.threeshelf$1.onClick(threeshelf.java:197)
      02-13 13:12:39.468: E/AndroidRuntime(2366):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
       02-13 13:12:39.468: E/AndroidRuntime(2366):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
     02-13 13:12:39.468: E/AndroidRuntime(2366):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
      02-13 13:12:39.468: E/AndroidRuntime(2366):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
       02-13 13:12:39.468: E/AndroidRuntime(2366):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
   02-13 13:12:39.468: E/AndroidRuntime(2366):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    02-13 13:12:39.468: E/AndroidRuntime(2366):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     02-13 13:12:39.468: E/AndroidRuntime(2366):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
       02-13 13:12:39.468: E/AndroidRuntime(2366):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
        02-13 13:12:39.468: E/AndroidRuntime(2366):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
```

Can anyone tell where I am getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this sql statement :

`String sql="UPDATE  LAST_OPEN  SET  LAST_OPEN='"+DATE+"'  WHERE  STUDENT_ID ="+STUDENT_ID+"    AND   ITEM_ID="+ITEM_ID+" AND   ITEM_NAME="+ITEM_TYPE+";";`

as I know, when you are using any string data in sql statement you need to add `''` in the beginning of the variable and at the end of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
LAST_OPEN=2012-02-13 13:12:39
```

with

```
LAST_OPEN = "2012-02-13 13:12:39"
```

The space between the numbers can be the problem. Hope this helps.